# What does a database log keep track of?

Tags: sql-server, database, logging, log4net

I'm quite new to SQL Server and was wondering what the difference between the SQL Server log is and a custom log (in my case, using log4net)? I guess there's more choice on what to log using `log4net`, but what things are automatically logged by the database? For example, if a user signs up to my site, would I have to manually log that transaction, or would that be recorded in the database's log automatically? I'm currently starting a project and would like to figure out exactly what I should bother logging.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apples and Oranges.

Log4net and other custom 'logging' is just a way to capture events an application is reporting. 'Log' in this context reffers to whatever store is used by this infrastucture to persist information about these events.

The database log on the other hand is something compeltely different. In order to maintain consistency and atomicity databases use a so called [Write-Ahead-Log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) protocol. In WAL all changes are first durable written into a journal, or log, before being applied to the data. This allows recovery to replay the log (the journal) and get the data back into a consistent state, by rolling back any uncommited work.

Database logs have absolutely nothing to do with your application code. Any database update will be automatically logged by the engine, simply because this is how any data is updated in a database. You cannot modify that, nor do you have any access to what's written in the log (strictly speaking you can look into the log, but you won't find any usefull information for your application).

Answer (score 2):

SQL log handles tansaction logging for rolling back or comiting data. They are usually only dealt with by someone who knows what they are doing restoring backups or shipping the logs to use for backups.

The log4net and other logging framweworks handle in code logging of exceptions, warning, or debug level info that you would like to output for your own info. They can be sent to a table in a database, command window, flat file or web service. Common logging scenarios are catching unhandled exceptions at the application level to help track down bugs, or in any try catch statements writing out the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

It keeps track of the transactions so it can roll them back or replay in case of a crash. Quite more involved than simple logging.

Comment: what would make a log shrink in size? is data removed after it is committed?

Comment: @Sergio--that depends on a lot of factors (DB, load, recovery model, etc.). In general, a SQL Server DB in "Simple" mode will wrap around its log file if it can. It will typically grow when it must and then only shrink if autoshrink is enabled (bad) or you manually shrink it with a command or SQL job.

Answer (score 1):

The two are almost completely unrelated.

A database log is used to rollback transactions, recover from crashes, etc. All good things to ensure database consistency. It has updates/inserts/deletes in it--not really anything about intent or what your app is *trying* to do unless it directly affects data in the database.

The application log on the other hand (with Log4Net) can be extremely useful when building and debugging your application. It is driven by *you* and should contain information that traces what your app is doing. This is something that can safely be turned off or reduced (by toggling the log level) when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server log file is actually used for maintaining it's own stability, but it's not terribly useful for normal developers. It's not what you think (and I what I thought), a list of SQL statements that have been run.  It's a propriety format designed to help SQL recover from a crash or roll back transactions.

If you need to track what's going on in the system, the SQL transaction log won't be helpful, and it would be very difficult to get that information back out.  Instead, I would suggest adding triggers on your tables that write information off to another table, or add some code in your data layer that saves off a log of what's going on.  It could be as simple as wrapping the SQL command object with your own implementation, which saved SQL statements off to log4net in addition to whatever normal code it was executing.

Answer (score 0):

It is the mechanism by which the RMDBS can assure [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) and [consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_(database_systems)), see [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).